# python pandas removes leading 0 while writing to csv

Tags: pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I am facing an issue which might be related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438109/why-does-pandas-remove-leading-zero-when-writing-to-a-csv) and others similar to this, i decided to create a sperate question because i feel my problem might have some additional things that i need to consider. Here is what I am facing right now.

I have a dataframe in pandas where it reads the data from sql and shows up something like following:
[image]

in picture it shows me that values have leading '0' and the datatype of this column is 'object'.

when i run this SQL and export to csv on my windows machine (python 3.7, pandas 1.0.3), it works exactly as required and shows the correct output,
the problem occurs when i try to run on my Linux machine (python 3.5.2, pandas 0.24.2), it always removes the leading zeros while writing to CSV, the csv looks like the following image:
[image]

i am not sure, what should i be changing to get the desired result at both environments. will appreciate any help.

Edit:
confirmed that read from SQL in ubuntu dataframe also has leading zeros:
[image]

Comment: Try converting that column to string type. `df['gid_num'] = df['gid_num'].astype('str')`

Comment: already tried, it doesnt work

Comment: Can you check if both env have leading zeros in pandas df. I'm thinking this is read time issue not write time issue.  if its reading without leading zeros in Linux then converting dtype will not help.

Comment: the read is from SQL and in query i have explicitly casted that column to varchar as well, can pandas still take it as in type?

Comment: Depends on what you are using for sql query. `read_sql` should take dtypes from sql types. I've seen some cases where it fails. But since your dtype is object pandas definately couldn't get the correct dtype for it from sql

Comment: just confirmed that read in ubuntu dataframe also has leading 0 in dataframe

Answer (score 0):

If you can use xlsx files instead of csv, then replace `df.to_csv` with `df.to_excel` and the file extension to xlsx.

With xlsx files you also get to store the types, so excel will not assume them to be numbers.

[csv vs excel](https://www.guru99.com/excel-vs-csv.html)

Comment: yes i understand your point, but unfortunately csv is required in my case