# How to avoid dropping leading 0 in data when writing to csv with PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, fips

## Problem

Note: [There is a similar problem here, but no satisfactory answer was given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66776864/python-pandas-removes-leading-0-while-writing-to-csv)

I'm using data with leading zeros and manipulating them in jupyter notebook python using pandas.

Im dealing with FIPS codes, which represent the counties in the US with a 6-digit code. Many of which start with a 0 (e.g. FIPS code "01001" represents Autauga County, Alabama).

It seems pandas assumes datatypes and need to be told explicitly what data types are. When numbers like "01001" are fed into a pandas dataframe, it seems like pandas assumes it is an int, and ints can't have leading 0's in python, so it drops it.

I know about the `dtype` argument for `read_csv()` in pandas, and I use that to force the data column with leading zeros to be read in as a string.

However, [there does not seem to be a `dtype` argument for the `to_csv()` method in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), and when I open up the final outputs, the leading 0s are mysteriously dropped again. It seems pandas might be assuming since they are mostly numbers, that it should be a float type, which drops the leading 0.

Any ideas on how to ensure the leading 0s remain?

Additional Info:

- `Python` version used: 3.9.7
- `jupyterlab` version: 3.2.1
- `pandas` version: 1.3.4

## Minimum Reproducible Example:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

input_csv = "index,FIPS\n \
             1,01001\n \
             2,02001 "

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(input_csv), dtype = {'FIPS':str})

print("dataframe: \n", df, "\n\n\n")
print("datatypes: \n")
print( df.info(), "\n\n\n")

df.to_csv("test.csv", index = False)
```

The outputs printed to the console shows that the leading zeros are not dropped in the dataframe, and it is stored as type string (called 'object' in pandas):

```
dataframe: 
    index    FIPS
0      1   01001
1      2  02001  



datatypes: 

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   index   2 non-null      int64 
 1   FIPS    2 non-null      object
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 160.0+ bytes
None
```

The output CSV is:

```
index   FIPS
1   1001
2   2001
```

Which has dropped zeros!

How can we make the output say "01001" under "FIPS"?

Comment: Unable to reproduce: your code works perfectly for me ... leading zeros are not dropped.

Comment: how are you viewing the output CSV? if you're using something other than a text editor (e.g. you're using Excel) it might be interpreting the field as a number type

Comment: *"The output CSV is"* not a raw output of CSV file...

Answer (score 0):

This should import it as a string:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv" , dtype = {'FIPS':"string"})
```